# VBA Update Statement - Missing Operator in Query Expression

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, syntax-error

First, I know that this question has been asked on this forum already, but each previous question differs from my situation and the solutions don't work.  My commas are all there and I'm using a very simple query.  Moving right along:

I'm using a linked table in Access, which links to a SQL Server database.  Everything works except this query.  If I run the text directly in SQL Server, it runs fine.  Therefore, the syntax of the query must be fine.

Here's what I'm running:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Update dbo_TS_Activity Set [Remarks] = ''Updated Remarks''   Where [id] = 1124 AND [Emp_Name] = ''CONFUSED''  AND [Approved] = 0"
```

**I get Run-time error '3075'
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''Updated Remarks''**

What I've tried:

- Single quotes
- Double quotes
- Double single (two apostrophes) quotes
- No quotes
- Opening the linked table and manually editing it (it works)
- Crying (just kidding)

Comment: Your context is a little unclear. Are `Updated Remarks` and `CONFUSED` literal text, or are they variables you're trying to concatenate into the SQL?

Comment: Those are just strings I'm trying to insert.  "Updated Remarks" is the string that is being updated.  "Confused" is the employee name that is being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Things finally fixed it... I ran the update in the query designer and it gave me this weird syntax of parenthesis around the WHERE statement so it looked like:

```
Where (((dbo_vw_TS_Activity.[id]) = 1124))
```

Finally, it wanted double-double-quotes for variables, like:

```
SET [Remarks] = ""The updated remarks...""
```

Suddenly, it's happy.  Consequently, I am too.

Comment: The parentheses in the first example are not necessary.  The query designer inserts them because they might have been necessary if the expression had been more complex.  The significant factor is the use of double quote characters rather than single quote characters.  To indicate a double-quote character in a VBA string, you need to double it, hence the need for double-double quotes in your string literal.  The string actually contains single double-quote characters.  For example, the string `""""` is one character long.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, AFAICT, from what you've posted along with your comment above.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "Update dbo_TS_Activity Set [Remarks] = 'Updated Remarks'   Where [id] = 1124 AND [Emp_Name] = 'CONFUSED'  AND [Approved] = 0"
```

Comment: Then what's Access getting all worked up over?  :)  It still won't work as VBA code.

Comment: @Ben: As I said, with what you posted it should work. It's hard to tell why it doesn't when you didn't post your actual query. (I doubt you're really trying to set `Remarks` to `Updated Remarks` for an employee named `CONFUSED`.)

Comment: Well, it was more complicated than that so I reduced it down to what my example was.  Even that simple statement fails.  That is the actual statement that fails.  It fails with variables or hard-coded values.